# holoviews - bokeh: histogram with log axis is blank

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, holoviews

I am trying to do a log plot in Jupyter Notebook using `Holoviews` with the `bokeh` backend.  If I set the y-axis to `log`, the plot shows only the axes with no data plotted and the following warning:

```
WARNING:param.HistogramPlot03582: Logarithmic axis range encountered value less than or equal to zero, please supply explicit lower-bound to override default of 0.010.
```

I can eliminate the warning by explicitly setting the y-axis range but there is still no plot.  The results can be replicated using this:

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
hv.extension('bokeh')

tl = [2079, 76, 15022, 3475, 31550, 38, 564, 551, 77, 117, 8962, 14, 186, 691, 896,
      2041, 1784, 5225, 2046, 15216, 176, 460, 219, 37903, 7806, 6325, 25396, 38016, 4154]

frequencies, edges = np.histogram(tl, 20)
frequencies = frequencies.astype('float') # not really required
frequencies[frequencies <= 0] = .1        # not really required

print('min freq', frequencies.min())
print('freq list', frequencies)

hv.Histogram((edges, frequencies)).opts(logy=True, height=400, width=400, ylim=(1E-1, 3E6))
```

The result will look like this.

[image]

Would anyone know of a workaround? Note: the problem is likely with `bokeh` to any `bokeh` solutions will likely work.

Comment: Plain Bokeh with `p.scatter((edges[:-1]+edges[1:])/2, freqs)` works as expected so perhaps there is just a Bokeh bug with drawing quads/bars on a log axis. Feel free to open a Bokeh issue *with a complete, pure Bokeh (no holoviews) reproducer*. All that said, a histogram on a log scale is not sensible mathematically in general, since it can admit zero values that are mathematically non-sensical on a log scale.

Comment: @bigreddot yeah not mathematically but log scale is best for illustration when the range of frequency is extremely large

Comment: FYI this is a known issue AFAICT: https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/2591